# cannot convert 'double (*)[10]' to 'double*' for argument

Tags: c++

Please help solving the compile time error. I have the declaration in different files as shown below

```
type.h
extern block posTime(const int row[MAX_ROW], int Flag, int n,double Time[]=0 );

a.cc
block posTime(   const int row[MAX_ROW],
                       int Flag,
                       int n,
                       double* eraseTime[]
                       )
```

...

```
eraseTime[0]=test[1];
```

..

```
b.cc
...
double eraseTime[MAX_ROW];

block newB = posTime (0,0,0,&eraseTime);
```

the last line `block newB = posTime (0,0,0,&eraseTime);` gives me the error, `cannot convert`double (*)[10] to `double* for argument 4`

I want to upadte the eraseTime in a.cc and use back in b.cc. Can I do that?

Comment: `&` is the address of operator. The type you get is a pointer to the type of what you take the address of. A pointer to an array is not in any way compatible with a pointer to an element of said array.

Comment: You want `double *eraseTime` or `double eraseTime[]` in the signature of `posTime`, not `double *eraseTime[]`.

Comment: The prototype in `type.h` and the definition in `a.cc` aren't the same. `Time` and `eraseTime` are not declared the same.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution (GCC 4.9.0 with C++11)

*test.hpp*

```
#define MAX_ROW 10
extern double posTime(const int row[MAX_ROW], int Flag, int n,double Time[]=0 );
```

*test1.cpp*

```
#include "test.hpp"

double posTime(   const int row[MAX_ROW],
                       int Flag,
                       int n,
                       double* eraseTime
                       )
{ eraseTime[0] = 2; eraseTime[1] = 3; return eraseTime[0]; }
```

*test.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.hpp"

double eraseTime[MAX_ROW] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ,7, 8, 9, 10 };

int main() {
    double newB = posTime (0,0,0,eraseTime);
    std::cout << "result: " << newB << std::endl;
    for (auto v : eraseTime) {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

compilation command: 
**g++ -std=c++11 -o e:\test.exe e:\test.cpp e:\test1.cpp**

or `double eraseTime[MAX_ROW]`, if you are using MAX_ROW in **int row** i don't see why not in **eraseTime** (probably some call location not in the sample restrict this use) or `double* eraseTime`.

Recommended change to use `std::array` (constant size) or `std::vector` (dynamic size).

Comment: :I changed as in your first option. I dont see any compile time error. But the point is I want to update the eraseTime in a.cc and use back in b.cc. When I try to update in a.cc, eraseTime[0]= test[1]; it gives me a runtime error. cant I access the variable and update it?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues here:

1. The signature in the header and in the implementation file are not the same: The header declares the last argument of `posTime()` to be of type `double*` (yes, pointer, not array!), while the implementation declares it to be of type `double**` (again, the array specification is converted to a pointer declaration because it is a function argument declaration).

   The result is, that the implementation declares an overload to the function declared in the header, not an implementation for it.
2. When you take the address of an array, you get a pointer to an array, i. e. a value of type `double (*)[MAX_ROW]`. This is incompatible to a `double**`, which is what your compiler is complaining about. To create a variable of this type, you must use the syntax `double (*myArrayPointer)[MAX_ROW];`. The parentheses are important because the array subscript operator has a higher precedence than the dereference operator, with the consequence that `double* myPointerArray[MAX_ROW];` declares an array of `MAX_ROW` pointers to doubles.

If you want to pass the array as a pointer to an array, you need to declare your function as

```
extern block posTime(const int row[MAX_ROW], int Flag, int n,double (*Time)[MAX_ROW]=0 );
```

This has the advantage that you get type checking on the length of the array, but the disadvantage that you cannot accept arrays of dynamic size. If you need this flexibility, the normal approach is to pass a pointer to the first element:

```
extern block posTime(const int row[MAX_ROW], int Flag, int n,double *Time=0 );
```

called with

```
block newB = posTime (0,0,0,eraseTime);
```

The call relies on array-pointer-decay to make a `double*` from your array identifier.